# I am trying to combine multiple csv files into one excel workbook as different sheets using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am able to create the sheets for different .csv files present in a folder in one Excel workbook using below java code But i am getting the data of all the csv file data in to single worksheet.
i am unable to get the data same as the orginal .csv files into specified sheets

```
public class CreateExlFile22{
     public static void main(String[]args){
    try{
           HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();


    File folder = new File("F:/csvfiles/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
     System.out.println(file.getName());




            String thisline;
            ArrayList<String> al = null;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

            HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());

            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
            {
                @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    return name.endsWith(".csv");
                }
            };


            File file1[]=folder.listFiles(filter);


            for(int r=0;r<file1.length;r++){
                File currentFile=file1[r];


                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    al = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String strar[] = thisline.split(",");

                    for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) {


                        al.add(strar[j]);
                    }

                    arlist.add(al);
                    //i++;

                } 

                fis.close();


                    for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {
                        ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);
                        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);

                        for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                            cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
                        }
                    }

                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F://NewWBFile.xls");
                    workbook.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();
                    br.close();


                    }


                    }

        }


    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
       }
   }
```

Comment: You've got a mess with all these nested loops. Try to split your single main method into several cohesive methods. And I can suggest that you don't need `for(int r=0;r<file1.length;r++)` loop at all - you've already iterating through the files in `for (File file : listOfFiles)` loop.

Comment: Take the filename filter out of the loop and get rid of the inner loop. Because of the inner loop, you are looping through the files multiple times.

Comment: when we are looping out the filter also we are getting all the data of csv file into one sheet and same data is copying in different sheets

Comment: Thanku Alexader Tokarev
We got the exact output when we are not using that forloop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class csvxls{
     public static void main(String[]args){
    try{

    File folder = new File("F:/csvfiles/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {


        if (file.isFile()) {

            String thisline;
            ArrayList<String> al = null;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

            HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());  
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    al = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String strar[] = thisline.split(",");

                    for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) { 
                        for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {

                            ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);


                            for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                                cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                            }
                        }

                        al.add(strar[j]);

                    } 

                  arlist.add(al);
                }

                fis.close();  
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F://NewWBFile.xls");
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
                br.close();
        }
        }

    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Nice code, But it does not print the last row of each file and if we have only 1 row in a file then it will print nothing except the column names.

Comment: This one is perfect https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949029/8663316

Answer (score 1):

This logic was causing multiple loop iteration and was skipping the last line of input CSV, better to ready the content separately and then prepare the excel content

Also you may want to replace the deprecated method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String thisline; 
    int rowCounter = 0;
    List<String> rowList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try { 

        File folder = new File("C:/poc/csvFiles/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        for (File file : listOfFiles) { 
            if (file.isFile()) { 
                
                rowCounter=0;   
                rowList = new ArrayList<String>();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(file.getName());
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                
                while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    rowList.add(thisline);
                }
                for (String rowLine: rowList) {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
                    rowCounter++;
                    String rowContentArr[] = rowLine.split(",");
                    for (int p = 0; p < rowContentArr.length; p++) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                        cell.setCellValue(rowContentArr[p]);
                    }
                } 
                fis.close();
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/poc/csvFiles/NewWBFile.xls");
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
                br.close();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```